# Is there a logical explanation why 非得不 and 非得 means must?

Tags: meaning, translation

I understand that 非 and 不 have negative meanings by themselves, and 得 means "must"
by itself. So with a double negative, which means affirmative positive. So far so good.

But 非得 by itself is also "must". Single negative. Also positive. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

非得 itself is always negative. The sentence contains only 非得 *could* be positive when there is a 2nd negative (most likely 不可) being omitted. This omission is common in colloquial language but not as common in written language or formal speeches.

Reference #1 below is a semantic analysis for the pattern 非..不可. It mentions the fact that 不可 can be omitted.

Reference #2 contains a lot of literature/publication citations where the 2nd negative of a double negative sentence is omitted.

In reference #3 the writer thinks the omission is grammatically wrong and is due to people not treating the language seriously.

References:

[1. “非……不可”句式在对外汉语教学中的研究](http://www.clra.edu.cn/showinfo.asp?id=841)

[2. 无可无不可的“不可”](http://archives.cnd.org/HXWK/author/XIONG-Youyu/kd091202-2.gb.html)

[3. 肯定、否定、否定之否定](http://blog.ifeng.com/article/1127222.html?flag=1)

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I have to understand from context if the 不可 is omitted or not?

Comment: @uncovery For 非得 you can safely assume it's meant to be double negative. For 非 (without 得) it depends on the context.